# Is there a way to do "git log -n 100 -from 200"?

Tags: git

Is there a way to do like paginated retrieval of commit history like `git log -n 100 -from 200`? It would fetch 100 commits after the first 200th commit. Is there such a feature?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do that with:

```
git log -n 100 --skip=200
```

The documentation for these options can be [found here](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-log.html#_commit_limiting).

Comment: That's it! Seems I have `skipped` that parameter ;)